# How to change the placeholder property of this multiple select with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am currently using the following script to make all multiple select dropdowns selectable through check boxes. There are around 30 such multiselect boxes in my form. When I use the placeholder option to automatically get the select box's title, it only gets the page's title.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-List-with-Checkboxes-MultiSelect.html

```
<select multiple title="example">
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[multiple]').multiselect({
        texts: {
            placeholder: $(this).attr('title')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You will have to use a loop to go through each select boxes and set place holder

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from @smilyface:

```
$.each($('select[multiple]'), function (key, selectbox) {
    $('#' + selectbox.id).multiselect({
        texts: {placeholder: $('#' + selectbox.id).attr('title')}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to show the selected option as button title, if so this code should work for you.

```
<select multiple title="example" id="multiple-select">
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>

$('#multiple-select').multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  buttonText: function(options) {
    if (options.length == 0) {
      return 'example';
    } else {
      return options.length + ' Selected';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Nope. It's the default text/placeholder text.